# Display PHP variable in <p>

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to display a PHP variable within a `<p>` tag but I either keep getting errors or the name of the variable is shown but not it's content.

Here is the code:

```
echo '<div class="item" style="background-color:'.$row[colour].';width:'.$row[width].'px;"><a href="'.$row[link_url].'" title="'.$row[name].'"><p>$row[name]</p></a></div>';
```

Where I have written:

```
<p>$row[name]</p>
```

will not show up in the browser correctly and instead will just show the name of the variable. If I surround the variable with '' I get an error regaurding syntax.

I have also tried to echo the variable:

```
<p><?php echo $row[name] ?></p>
```

But on the website nothing is displayed at all and when I look in the FireFox inspector I see this:
[image]
The code has automatically been commented out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `'. $row[name] . '`

like this

`echo '<div class="item" style="background-color:'.$row[colour].';width:'.$row[width].'px;"><a href="'.$row[link_url].'" title="'.$row[name].'"><p>' . $row[name]. '</p></a></div>';`

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

When interpolating array values in strings you need to use curly brackets and double quotes.

```
echo ...."\"><p>{$row['name']}</p></a></div>";
```

When you use single quotes, php does not interpolate variable names inside the string. Instead, it just prints the names, which is what you're seeing in the source code.

And your array keys should be strings, so `['name']` instead of `[name]`

Answer (score 2):

You have to concatenate the php variable.

Replace

```
echo '<div class="item" style="background-color:'.$row[colour].
     ';width:'.$row[width].'px;"><a href="'.$row[link_url].
     '" title="'.$row[name].'"><p>$row[name]</p></a></div>';
```

with

```
echo '<div class="item" style="background-color:'.$row[colour].
     ';width:'.$row[width].'px;"><a href="'.$row[link_url].
     '" title="'.$row[name].'"><p>'.$row[name].'</p></a></div>';
```

Notice **`'"><p>'.$row[name].'</p></a></div>';`**

Comment: Thanks! This helped alot

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is 100% as I am half asleep but at least it will help you with your array a bit.

```
echo "<div class=\"item\" style=\"background-color:".$row['colour'].";width:".$row['width']."px;\"><a href=".$row['link_url']." title=".$row['name']."><p>".$row['name']."</p></a></div>";
```